# Fortify Json Injection in .NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, fortify

I am using Newtonsoft.Json for deserializing a json string but fortify complained that I am using unvalidated json. i then added a check using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema but it now complains even more

```
var schema = JsonSchema.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(typeof(T)));
JToken token = JArray.Parse(json); -- Vulnerability
IList<string> errors;
if (token.IsValid(schema, out errors))
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); -- Vulnerability
}
```

Any advice on how to validate Json string?

> On line 23 of , the method DeserializeObject() writes
>   unvalidated input into JSON. This call could allow an attacker to
>   inject arbitrary elements or attributes into the JSON entity.

Comment: Define `complains`. Do you have an exception or error message?

Comment: [If this is how they roll, I'd turn Fortify off and move on](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K0v6i.png)

Comment: please, update your question with exact error message generated by Fortify

Comment: Where does `json` come from?

Comment: Json comes from an internal REST service.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apologies for the late response, I managed to fix/deceive fortify. Here is the fix

```
byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(jsonBytes))
{
    output = Deserialize<List<T>>(stream);
}

 public TResult Deserialize<TResult>(Stream responseStream)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer
                {
                    MissingMemberHandling =
                        EnforceMissingMemberHandling ? MissingMemberHandling.Error : MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
                    NullValueHandling = IgnoreNullValues ? NullValueHandling.Ignore : NullValueHandling.Include
                };

                return serializer.Deserialize<TResult>(reader);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice.

Comment: But the encoding in StreamReader could be different from UTF8. Maybe that's why Fortify is unable to show error??

Comment: Your method is a bit incomplete, the `IgnoreNullValues` and `EnforceMissingMemberHandling` seem to be missing declaration.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like in your case Fortify complains that you use `json` from untrusted source, this is what is said in [Fortify documentation](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.dataflow.java.json_injection#C%23%2FVB.NET%2FASP.NET):

> The semantics of JSON documents and messages can be altered if an application constructs JSON from unvalidated input. In a relatively benign case, an attacker may be able to insert extraneous elements that cause an application to throw an exception while parsing a JSON document or request. In a more serious case, such as that involving JSON injection, an attacker may be able to insert extraneous elements that allow for the predictable manipulation of business critical values within a JSON document or request.

If you receive `json` from a web service that you own, you can probably disregard Fortify's warning. However, keep in mind that you are calling `JArray.Parse()` on the input and presume it will be a valid array, but if it isn't, you would get `JsonReaderException`. Also, you don't really validate your JSON against a schema, please, see [JSON.NET example](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) to see how to specify JSON schema.

To be honest, I would be interested to know myself how Fortify would expect one to validate JSON received from some third-party web service.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for a solution, i have done the following and it seems to be working as expected.

## 1 Get the JSON sample and infer schema using online tools.

## 2 Add a separate method to Validate JSON before parsing or deserializing it.

## 3 After validating the JSON using Schema then proceed for the normal operation whatever you wanted to do.